# ng-boilerplate grunt scripts compilation

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, ngboilerplate

I would like to be able to duplicate ng-boilerplate's script compilation process in my own app, but I am unable to get it working.

I am referring to having this line in index.html be compiled into a list of all the scripts in my app:

```
<!-- compiled JavaScript --><% scripts.forEach( function ( file ) { %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%= file %>"></script><% }); %>
```

I added the filterForJS function and registered the multi task in my gruntfile.js, but it is not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the options for the index task?

```

```
/**
 * The `index` task compiles the `index.html` file as a Grunt template. CSS
 * and JS files co-exist here but they get split apart later.
 */
index: {

  /**
   * During development, we don't want to have wait for compilation,
   * concatenation, minification, etc. So to avoid these steps, we simply
   * add all script files directly to the `<head>` of `index.html`. The
   * `src` property contains the list of included files.
   */
  build: {
    dir: '<%= build_dir %>',
    src: [
      '<%= vendor_files.js %>',
      '<%= build_dir %>/src/**/*.js',
      '<%= html2js.common.dest %>',
      '<%= html2js.app.dest %>',
      '<%= vendor_files.css %>',
      '<%= recess.build.dest %>'
    ]
  },

  /**
   * When it is time to have a completely compiled application, we can
   * alter the above to include only a single JavaScript and a single CSS
   * file. Now we're back!
   */
  compile: {
    dir: '<%= compile_dir %>',
    src: [
      '<%= concat.compile_js.dest %>',
      '<%= vendor_files.css %>',
      '<%= recess.compile.dest %>'
    ]
  }
},
```

```