# Karma testing the ng-boilerplate app gives "Invalid Config file error". Why?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, ngboilerplate

I downloaded the [`ng-boilerplate` app](https://github.com/ngbp/ngbp) from Github and I'm going through it to help me learn about AngularJS and testing.

One of the first things I did was try to learn how Karma testing works. So I opened a command prompt inside the Karma folder, and typed:

```
karma start karma-unit.tpl.js
```

which I'd expect to return perfect test results (since I haven't touched any of the code). However, instead, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Imray\stuff\Angular JS\ng-boilerplate\karma\karma-unit.tpl.js:12
      <% scripts.forEach( function ( file ) { %>'<%= file %>',
      ^
ERROR [config]: Invalid config file!
  SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.parseConfig (C:\Users\Imray\stuff\Angular JS\ng-boilerplate\node_modules\karma\lib\config.js:250:22)
    at Object.exports.start (C:\Users\Imray\stuff\Angular JS\ng-boilerplate\node_modules\karma\lib\server.js:286:20)
    at Object.exports.run (C:\Users\Imray\stuff\Angular JS\ng-boilerplate\node_modules\karma\lib\cli.js:229:25)
    at requireCliAndRun (C:\Users\Imray\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\karma-cli\bin\karma:24:16)
```

Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hm not sure but maybe you have to run a Grunt task before running the `karma start karma-unit.tpl.js` since you have some unprocessed string there.

`<% scripts.forEach( function ( file ) { %>'<%= file %>',` doesn't look like valid javascript  but more like a build string

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20232899/ng-boilerplate-grunt-scripts-compilation)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the karmaconfig task:

```
/**
 * In order to avoid having to specify manually the files needed for karma to
 * run, we use grunt to manage the list for us. The `karma/*` files are
 * compiled as grunt templates for use by Karma. Yay!
 */
grunt.registerMultiTask( 'karmaconfig', 'Process karma config templates', function () {
var jsFiles = filterForJS( this.filesSrc );

grunt.file.copy( 'karma/karma-unit.tpl.js', grunt.config( 'build_location' ) + '/karma-unit.js', {
    process: function ( contents, path ) {
        return grunt.template.process( contents, {
            data: {
                scripts: jsFiles
            }
        });
    }
});
```

});

Or you simply removed it, or forgot to add it before your karma tasks:

```
grunt.registerTask( 'build', [
        'clean', 'html2js', 'jshint:source', 'jshint:test', 'karmaconfig',
        'karma:continuous', 'karma:coverage'
    ]);
```

(removed a couple of tasks it make it easier to see. The karmaconfig task also relies on a filterForJs function. But this is all included in ng-boilerplate so I didn't explicitly add it here)